# Structure/ method for folder storage

Tags: database, git, github

Is anyone aware of what method / structure does google drive use to upload a whole folder?
And how to use the same method with git push for uploading that folder in a similar way as github does.

1- Storing folder as a zip and unzipping and showing it on.the client side would be inefficient i think.

2- Creating a new row for each file and storing it along with the path and then getting all the rowa related to the path is also a very inefficient approach.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Git is a version control system and GitHub is a place to store your project which you use Git. Let's give an example. GitHub is like Instagram but for code commits not for photos. So all other developers can see/fetch/push/comment on those commits. It's not like Google Drive. Google Drive is a "file storage".

If you want to push (upload) a folder or a .zip file, first you need to commit it with Git and later push it to GitHub. Don't forget to create a repository on GitHub first and remember to set it as "private" if you need.

I suggest you read this e-book: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Comment: No sir i think you misunderstood the question. I am trying to make the functionality of uploading folders as github does. I mean when you push your code to github it must be storing the tree structure of the folder somehow in their db for showing at the frontend.. so i wanted to ask how does github or google drive store the folder. The structure / method. @Eray

Comment: Ah, sorry. I think I misunderstood the question. But still couldn't understand what you meant exactly (sorry). Git's itself is storing the workspace tree structure as references in its own database (not a real database, I meant `.git` folder but it's not important at this point). And sending these references to GitHub so GitHub can understand the structure of the project (folder, files etc.). But I guess this is not what you are asking :-( Maybe someone else can help you. This is what I can explain, because I couldn't get the question.

Comment: I am sorry if I wasn't clear with my question. I meant to ask that I am using my remote git server, so now if I want to show the file folder(tree structure) in my frontend as github does what should be the method for it? How does GitHub shows folder data in its frontend? @Eray.